Django REST Framework: can't properly annotate values to many-to-many model, keep getting error Field name <field> is not valid for model <m2m model>
I have a model for recipes and many-to-many model that represents favorite recipes by users:
class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=LENGTH_FOR_TEXTFIELD)
    image = models.ImageField()
    text = models.TextField(max_length=LENGTH_FOR_TEXTFIELD)
    cooking_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class FavoriteRecipe(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe.name

After POST request an entry in that model is created (recipe ID and user ID) and i am trying to write a serializer for response that will contain info about recipe itself:
class FavoriteRecipeSerializerForRead(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FavoriteRecipe
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image', 'cooking_time')

So the problem is that i cannot insert into this serializer any recipe-field because i keep getting  error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `name` is not valid for model `FavoriteRecipe`

I tried to imply select_related() and .annotate(field=Value(Query)) in my viewset like this but nothing seems to work:
class FavoriteRecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FavoriteRecipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FavoriteRecipeSerializerForRead

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = FavoriteRecipe.objects.all().annotate(
            name=Value(
                Recipe.objects.filter(id=self.id).values('cooking_time',)
            )
        )
        return queryset

The question is: how could i do this the proper way?

Why not serialize the Recipe?

Why not serialize the Recipe?
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image', 'cooking_time')
we can use this for Recipes that are not a Favorite one.
In the ViewSet, we can work with the favorite Recipes of a user:
class FavoriteRecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Recipe.objects.filter(favoriterecipe__user=self.request.user)
You will need to add authentication [drf-doc] to ensure there is a request.user.

I tried to use recipe serialization just like you suggested, but i got an error:
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `FavoriteRecipeSerializerForRead`.
backend-1   | The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `FavoriteRecipe` instance.
backend-1   | Original exception text was: 'FavoriteRecipe' object has no attribute 'name'.


@Антон: you probably forgot to change the model = ... to Recipe.

I wish i did but model was changed:
class FavoriteRecipeSerializerForRead(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image', 'cooking_time')

Still i think i'm definitely doing something wrong here

You also changed the queryset to queryset = Recipe.objects.all().

Yes, i also changed queryset and added def_get_queryset like you suggested

I could probably get required fields through SerializerMethodField but i think this is not the best way to do it

Found problem in my code, your solution worked like a charm, thank you!
